# In VSCode, how can I get color previews for a non-standard format such as, "--color-rgb: ##, ##, ##;"?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, colors

I have tried many VS Code extensions that will show a color palette pop up, or preview, for standard CSS & SCSS color styles such as `#ff0000`, `rgb(255, 0, 0)`,  `rgba(255,0,0,1)`, `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)`, etc.

However I'm working with a bootstrap stylesheet that uses a non-standard value `255, 0, 0` format, without a leading 'rgb', that facilitates these colors being processed via mixins, and other SASS functions, that integrate opacity, or other transforms, on the base color values.

Instead, these non-standard bootstrap, color definitions add the 'rgb' to the name of the CSS variable instead of the color value.

`--bs-body-bg-rgb: 255, 0, 0;`

[image]

None of the many color extensions I've tried in my search seem to have an option to recognize this style of non-conforming variable, or the ability to define custom formats.

Does anyone have experience using a VS Code color extension that does have a feature to preview non-standard color formats, such as, `--bs-body-bg-rgb: 255, 0, 0;`, or has, a customizable setting that allows one to define a non-standard format it should recognize as a color?

Comment: highly related but I wouldn't quite call a duplicate: [How can a VS Code extension provide colour decorations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77154091/11107541)

Comment: `color: {red}, {green}, {blue}`  is not a valid HTML color format, which means the only way to have an IDE extension which understands what those numbers mean and preview them color would be if you wrote the said extension yourself. I'm just wondering why you want that, since you will only preview the base color, not the result of whatever sass functions you have, applying color transparency, right?

Comment: @tao 1) they're aware that it's not valid CSS. 2) an extension might exist which does this already. thus, the answer is not strictly necessarily "you _must_ write the extension yourself" 3) I wouldn't be so quick to think that it wouldn't be useful to see the source colour.

Comment: @starball, 1) there's no indication OP is aware it's not a valid color format, what are you basing your assumption on? 2) Why would an extension assume `color: ##, ##, ##` should be parsed as `rgb` and not `hsl` or `hwb`?