# How can a VS Code extension provide colour decorations?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to create colour decorations like those that VS Code draws for CSS colour literals. I know that VS Code has the `editor.defaultColorDecorators` setting, but I want to add support for patterns that are not matched by VS Code's builtin functionality. How can I do that in a VS Code extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [`DocumentColorProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentColorProvider), which allows you to provide [`ColorPresentation`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ColorPresentation)s and document colours.

For related historical discussion on the design of this part of the extension API, see [ColorProvider API: Let extensions define the color formats
#34366](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34366) and [Color Picker: Finalize Color Picker API #32235](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32235).

If you want to look at examples of how more complicated language provider extensions do this, you could take a look at the Dart/Flutter extension: [[Feature Request] Color Picker for Flutter's Color(s) similar to CSS #3240](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3240), which [does it at the layer of its LSP server](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/3238b2c09c1e2fc023363ea33902d93bcc8b3d79), or [the C# extension](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/e519c55a86df49e242a12f1b2e38c9685fd95930/src/razor/src/documentColor/documentColorHandler.ts#L40), which makes use of VS Code's [`vscode.executeDocumentColorProvider`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/280c840f872a5d791d79abda2cadac638d21d880/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostApiCommands.ts#L311) command and also does most of the work at the lanugage server layer.